SharePoint List - Ticket System for Technical Service
I have a small team of service technicians and I am trying to organize our customer requests in a SharePoint List.
I used 2 different views to separate requests, which are currently supported in the hotline remotely, and for tickets where we need to visit the customer on-site.
For this I included a column (multiple choice) to indicate if an on-site visit is necessary. By filtering the 2nd view "Missions" on only tickets with the On-site mission necessary, I have a 2nd set of stati to follow up on the planning status of those.

Now I am encountering 2 problems:

I would like to show specific column on the cards in the Mission View. But the Card Designer won't show all Columns existing in the List. I tried to change different types of columns (multiple choice, single line text, Yes/No, ...) but I don't understand the logic, which Columns are selectable for the Card Designer. Can someone tell me how to display other columns inside the card designer?



When opening a card in the gallery view, I would like them to show different Columns depending on from which view the card was opened. e.g. for the Mission View, I want to maintain and see if there are spare parts or tools necessary for the on-site visit. But I want to hide this information / fields, while I am working on the card in the Case View.
Currently, changing the contents of the card will be saved for both views. Could you let me know if this is generally possible? If not, I will have to show all information on the content of the card at any time...



For the first question, go to List settings -> Views -> Choose the board view ->  Select the check box next to each column you want to show or hide in this view.
For the second question, it is not possible to show or hide columns in the form  based on different views.

Have the required fields been added to the view?  If not, you won't be able to see them to change the card settings.

I’ll try that.i guess the 2nd question is not possible?
